Can I use a likelihood-ratio test when the measure of deviance between two models is not the log-likelihood?
We use the Nelder-Mead optimziation algorithm (as implemented in the dfoptim package for R) to fit a model with several free parameters.
What is minimised (in our current implementation) when searching for the optimal parameter values is, however, not the log-likelihood but the quadratic difference between predicted values (by the model) and observed values in the empirical data.
Hence, the best-fitted model returns the lowest quadratic difference between predicted and actual values that was found.
We would now like to do model-comparisons by fixing one parameter to 0 in one version of the model and allow it to be estimated in the other model (i.e., comparing the difference in fit of two nested models and whether the fit significantly improves, when the parameter in question is free).
To compare if the one model fits better than the other, one approach would be to use a Likelihood-Ratio test. However, since our deviance measure is not the log-likelihood (but the quadratic difference), my question is whether test-results are trustworthy in this case or if there is another model-comparison test-statistic that should be used in this case.

I don't think it would make any sense to use a likelihood ratio test in this case. Consider the thought experiment of scaling your response variable by a factor of 1000; then I would expect your squared deviation measure to increase by a factor of a million ($1000^2$), without any real change in the relative goodness of fit of the models.
There are various "likelihood-free" inference methods (e.g. approximate Bayesian computation, synthetic likelihood), but they generally require that you have a method for simulating from the generating process ...

Is what's described in the question substantively different from what nls() does (except for the optimization algorithm)? If not, couldn't one normalize by the residual standard error to handle scale changes?

Yes, if you were willing to assume a Gaussian distribution and profile out the residual standard deviation parameter (i.e. sd = RSS/n or sd = RSS/(n-1). But that's not at all what the OP said they were doing - they're just using the (unscaled) difference of RSS, AFAICT.

According to this: https://sites.duke.edu/bossbackup/files/2013/02/FTestTutorial.pdf could an F-test be used in this case?

Yes, I think so, because the RSS are in the numerator and the denominator, so changes in scale would cancel out.

If you wanted to post your own answer pointing to the F-test solution that would be fine, otherwise I can edit my question to include it.
